# Parsing XML-RPC Response from wp.getCategories

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, xml-rpc

**THE PROBLEM**
I am using cURL and PHP to retrieve a list of categories from a Wordpress site via XML-RPC (wp.getCategories or metaWeblog.getCategories), but I'm having trouble parsing the response, as it seems very complicated.

My code should parse the response and create a simple dropdown menu:

This is not supposed to be actual working code, but how I picture it to work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($categories);
$select_string = "<select name=\"cats\">";
foreach ($xml as $category) {
    $select_string .= "<option value=\"" . $category->value . "\">" . $category->name . "</option>";
}
$select_string .= "</select>";
```

And the response that I'm trying to parse is (this is what the simplexml_load_string outputs):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[param] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [array] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [data] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [value] =&gt; Array
                                    (
                                        [0] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [struct] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [member] =&gt; Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryId
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; 4
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [1] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; parentId
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; 0
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [2] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; description
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; News
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [3] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryDescription
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [4] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryName
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; News
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [5] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; htmlUrl
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [6] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; rssUrl
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/feed/
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [struct] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [member] =&gt; Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryId
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; 5
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [1] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; parentId
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; 4
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [2] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; description
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; Testimonials
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [3] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryDescription
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [4] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryName
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; Testimonials
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [5] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; htmlUrl
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/testimonials/
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [6] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; rssUrl
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/testimonials/feed/
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [2] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [struct] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [member] =&gt; Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryId
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; 1
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [1] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; parentId
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; 0
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [2] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; description
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; Uncategorized
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [3] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryDescription
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                                    (
                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [4] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; categoryName
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; Uncategorized
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [5] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; htmlUrl
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/uncategorized/
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [6] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] =&gt; rssUrl
                                                                        [value] =&gt; SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                            (
                                                                                [string] =&gt; http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/uncategorized/feed/
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I have tried to iterate through the array of members with this in the foreach statement, but it doesn't work:

```
$xml->param->value->array->data->value->struct->member;
```

Does anyone know an easy way to easily parse the data here?

ACTUAL XML:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<methodresponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
      <array><data>
  <value><struct>
  <member><name>categoryId</name><value><string>4</string></value></member>
  <member><name>parentId</name><value><string>0</string></value></member>
  <member><name>description</name><value><string>News</string></value></member>
  <member><name>categoryDescription</name><value><string></string></value></member>
  <member><name>categoryName</name><value><string>News</string></value></member>
  <member><name>htmlUrl</name><value><string>http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/</string></value></member>
  <member><name>rssUrl</name><value><string>http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/feed/</string></value></member>
</struct></value>
  <value><struct>
  <member><name>categoryId</name><value><string>5</string></value></member>
  <member><name>parentId</name><value><string>4</string></value></member>
  <member><name>description</name><value><string>Testimonials</string></value></member>
  <member><name>categoryDescription</name><value><string></string></value></member>
  <member><name>categoryName</name><value><string>Testimonials</string></value></member>
  <member><name>htmlUrl</name><value><string>http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/testimonials/</string></value></member>
  <member><name>rssUrl</name><value><string>http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/testimonials/feed/</string></value></member>
</struct></value>
  <value><struct>
  <member><name>categoryId</name><value><string>1</string></value></member>
  <member><name>parentId</name><value><string>0</string></value></member>
  <member><name>description</name><value><string>Uncategorized</string></value></member>
  <member><name>categoryDescription</name><value><string></string></value></member>
  <member><name>categoryName</name><value><string>Uncategorized</string></value></member>
  <member><name>htmlUrl</name><value><string>http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/uncategorized/</string></value></member>
  <member><name>rssUrl</name><value><string>http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/uncategorized/feed/</string></value></member>
</struct></value>
</data></array>
      </value>

  </params>
</methodresponse>
```

Thanks.
Rick

**FINAL SOLUTION (With the help provided by E_p)**
This builds a dropdown menu of the categories from the XML-RPC response from wp.getCategories or metaWeblog.getCategories.

```
$categories =  wpGetCategories($url, $username, $password);
$select_string = "<select name=\"cats\">";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($categories);
foreach ($xml->params->param->value->array->data->value as $dataSet) {
    foreach ($dataSet->struct->member as $member) {
        if ($member->name == "categoryId") $cat_id = $member->value->string;
        if ($member->name == "description") $cat_name = $member->value->string;
    } 
    $select_string .= "<option value=\"" . $cat_id . "\">" . $cat_name . "</option>";  
}
$select_string .= "</select>";
```

Comment: Can you add `print_r($categories)` .. like to see how the real xml looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried :

```
<?php 

    $str = "<a><tests><test>1</test><test>2</test><test>3</test><test>4</test></tests></a>";
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

    foreach ($xml->tests->test as $test) {
        echo "Test #: " . $test . PHP_EOL;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }
```

returns:

```
Test #: 1
Test #: 2
Test #: 3
Test #: 4
```

So in your case `foreach ($xml->param->value->array->data->value->struct->member as $member)` should work

Can you provide xml you parse.

Tried with your xml (it had syntax error):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('your xml here');
foreach ($xml->params->param->value->array->data->value as $dataSet) {
    foreach ($dataSet->struct->member as $member) {
        echo 'Name: ' . $member->name  . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Value: ' . $member->value->string  . PHP_EOL;
    }   
    echo PHP_EOL;                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

output

```
Name: categoryId
Value: 4
Name: parentId
Value: 0
Name: description
Value: News
Name: categoryDescription
Value: 
Name: categoryName
Value: News
Name: htmlUrl
Value: http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/
Name: rssUrl
Value: http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/feed/

Name: categoryId
Value: 5
Name: parentId
Value: 4
Name: description
Value: Testimonials
Name: categoryDescription
Value: 
Name: categoryName
Value: Testimonials
Name: htmlUrl
Value: http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/testimonials/
Name: rssUrl
Value: http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/news/testimonials/feed/

Name: categoryId
Value: 1
Name: parentId
Value: 0
Name: description
Value: Uncategorized
Name: categoryDescription
Value: 
Name: categoryName
Value: Uncategorized
Name: htmlUrl
Value: http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/uncategorized/
Name: rssUrl
Value: http://lubranochiropractic.com/category/uncategorized/feed/
```

Though it works parse should be more complicated as they use xml to specify types.

Comment: And you might convert xml to array and cache array with apc or something